# Hiding Featured Checkbox setting from backend product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, product

With WooCommerce, I would like to hide or remove **`FEATURED`** checkbox from product pages settings in the Backend (Admin), see the screenshot below.

I have tried with CSS **`display:none`** but it does't work.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

[image: screenshot of the backend feature setting on products pages]
<sub>(source: [imgh.us](https://imgh.us/featured.png))</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Show us your code so we can look into your issue, and if you really want help, show us your efforts. may you please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible with a custom function hooked in **`admin_head`** wordpress hook, that will inject in the admin head some CSS rules. Here we target the product post types pages.

Here is that code:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'hiding_and_set_product_settings');
function hiding_and_set_product_settings(){
    echo '<style>
        .post-type-product #catalog-visibility-select p:nth-of-type(2),
        .post-type-product #catalog-visibility-select label[for=_featured],
        .post-type-product #catalog-visibility-select input[type=checkbox] { visibility: hidden !important; display none !important;}
    </style>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

See this screenshot of my test raw server:

[image]

Comment: @Paradox Sorry but this works perfectly see the screenshot of my raw test server (update in my answer)… May be you have to adapt the CSS selectors to your language wordpress installation

Comment: YES. I tried again and wonderfull now work !! Thank you very very very much!!! Wonderful Codes !!!